# Eclipse + MySql + Hibernate, a good intro?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate, orm

I'm looking for a tutorial explaining how to work with these 3 technologies, found this [one](http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-tools-1.html), but it's working with HyperSql DB (yeah, I edited hibernate.cfg.xml to connect with MySql... but I just received a bunch of errors).

Comment: Here, http://pastebin.com/TjySJGcz

Comment: There is something wrong with the id generation, is the primary key defined as autoincrement? Can you show the DDL script for the table (and confirm you MySQL version)?

Comment: I'm not using script to create the table, and I'm not able to define the primary key as auto-increment, I receive this "Invalid default value for 'COURSE_ID'" in Toad for Mysql when try to do this, here is my hibernate.cfg.xml pastebin.com/3YWtamfW, Course.hbm.xml, pastebin.com/KdtFE9Td

Comment: The DDL script is that, http://pastebin.com/h9E0rwyy

Comment: @Wilhelm - you are supposed to mark an answer as accepted (using the tick below the vote counter). That answer should be the one that helped you most in solving your problem (or your own answer, if it is the only full answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table creation script is wrong for the hibernate generator strategy you're currently using. As I said, your primary key should be defined as autoincrement:

```
CREATE TABLE COURSES (
  COURSE_ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  COURSE_NAME varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (COURSE_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

You should let SchemaExport generate your DDL for you, it will typically prevent such mistakes ;)

Answer (score 1):

You might try setting `<generator class="identity">`. But `native` should also be working if you have set the database column to be `auto_increment`.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved using "[Toad for MySQL](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/)" for creating the table, when setting the column to be the primary key, I just cleaned the "Default value" and did set the AutoIncrement property to true.